# Why the following JavaScript regex could not work?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, regex-lookarounds

```
s='<img src="http://25.media.tumblr.com/xxxxx/tumblr_xxx_1280.jpg">'
p=/(?=<img src=")http:\/\/\d*\.media\.tumblr\.com\/\w*\/?tumblr_\w*_\d{3,4}\.\w{3,3}(?=")/g
s.match(p) # return null
```

However, the following works:

```
p=/(<img src=")http:\/\/\d*\.media\.tumblr\.com\/\w*\/?tumblr_\w*_\d{3,4}\.\w{3,3}(?=")/g
```

Comment: Are you sure that the second regex works? I tried it and it matches everything except the last two characters ( "> ).

Comment: @dreboy just mean it will successfully return a match result （´◔౪◔）, I just want to get the hyperlink. To match (">) you may use "> instead of (?=").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ?= : Positive lookahead. Matches a group **after** your main expression
>   without including it in the result.

You are looking for a positive lookbehind, as you are trying to match something **before** your main expression, if you are trying to **extract the URL** only.

```
p=/(?<=img src=....
     ^ positive look-behind
```

**EDIT:**

They aren't supported in JavaScript(as the comments indicate), so you'd have to resort to [trickery](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript).

However, if you are trying to extract the URL, it might be easier to split it over 2 steps, getting the entire match and then removing the `<img src=...` part.

Comment: Look-behind is not supported in javascript. http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

Comment: You can match the `src` inside a capturing group and you wouldn't need any lookahead/lookbehind.

Answer (score 0):

Your first regex cannot match because it uses a *zero-width* look-ahead that contradicts the pattern that follows it.

A regex cannot match `"<img src="` and in the same place in the string also match e.g. `"http://25"`.